# Using bootstrap offline

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, electron, offline

I am creating a desktop app using Electron and I would like to include Bootstrap. However, I want my app to be usable offline once it's published, and I'm wondering if there's a way to statically save the applicable Bootstrap elements within my app so that it's standalone.
Any ideas?

Comment: Download bootstrap from here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/download/ Put it in the source code of your electron app and link using relative path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the `Bootstrap 4` files [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v4.0.0/bootstrap-4.0.0-dist.zip)

Add this line:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap_folder/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">`

I assumed that you want `Bootstrap 4` because it is one of your tags.

Answer (score 2):

Create the three files in a directory in your project folder

```
/my project
.
. index.html
. 
. /resources
. . 
. . bootstrap.css
. . jquery.js
. . bootstrap.js
```

in those three files, visit the href links from your `<link>` and `<script>` tags, copy and paste in to each one the [contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN7yp.png)

> bootstrap 3.4
>
> https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
> https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js
> https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js

then you can include them with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/bootstrap.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="/resources/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="/resources/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

there are also instructions on the bootstrap website for other ways of downloading offline installations and even compiling your own custom bootstrap bundle (e.g. with sass mix-ins for custom variables like breakpoint widths)

Bootstrap 3.4 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/getting-started/#download

Bootstrap 4.3 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/download/